# Zeros of $\exp(-x^2)$ and its derivatives

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function, roots

> **Question**: Let $f(x)=e^{-x^2}:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. Is there some bounded interval $I=[-a,a]\subset\Bbb R$ so that all zeros of $f^{(n)}$ (the $n$-th derivative) are contained in $I$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$?

My approach was to express $f^{(n)}$ as $P_n(x)e^{-x^2}$ for some polynomials $P_n$. We find

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}[P_n(x)e^{-x^2}]=P_n'(x)e^{-x^2}-2xP_n(x)e^{-x^2}=\underbrace{(P_n'(x)-2xP_n(x))}_{P_{n+1}(x)}e^{-x^2}.$$

Together with $P_0(x)=1$, this defines exactly the (physicis's) [Hermite polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) (thanks to gammatester for pointing this out in the comments). So the question is essentially whether all zeros of the Hermite polynomials are contained in some interval $I=[-a,a]$.

Comment: Closely related to the [physicists' Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials).

Comment: @gammatester Indeed, I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/104875/415941) with your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In fact the zeroes of the Hermite polynomials are known to be asymptotically [semicircularly distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_semicircle_distribution) in the interval $[-2 \sqrt{n}, 2 \sqrt{n}]$; see, for example, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03724) by Kornyik and Michaeletzky.