# How to prove the laguerre polynomial has n zero point?

Tags: calculus, laguerre-polynomials

Here is an equation:

$$
e^x\frac{d^n(x^ne^{-x})}{dx^n}=0
$$

Now I want to prove that this equation has $n$ different roots.

I tried to convert the equation to this form:

$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}C_n^k(-1)^{n-k}\frac{n!}{k!}x^{n-k}=0
$$

But I don't know how to prove that it has exactly $n$ different roots. So what should I do?

A hint is enough!

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Explicit_examples_and_properties_of_the_generalized_Laguerre_polynomials) suggests using Sturm sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Rolle's theorem is enough. $f(x)=x^n e^{-x}$ has a root with multiplicity $n$ at the origin and it vanishes at $+\infty$.
$f'(x)$ has a root with multiplicity $n-1$ at the origin, a simple root at some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^+$ (local maximum for $f$) and it vanishes at $+\infty$. $f''(x)$ has a root with multiplicity $n-2$ at the origin, a simple root somewhere between $0$ and $x_0$ and a simple root somewhere after $x_0$. Use induction and you are done.

The same argument also applies to (shifted) Legendre polynomials, essentially given by $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(x^n(1-x)^n\right)$.

The largest root of a Laguerre polynomial can be estimated using the techniques shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2525094/proving-that-all-the-real-roots-of-hermite-polynomials-are-in-sqrt4n1-s/2525224#2525224) for Hermite polynomials.